# JavaScript: wait for onclick-event from user (who compares 2 pics) by making a pause inside custom compare function for standard JS array.sort?

Tags: javascript, html, sortcomparefunction

I need to arrange 8 images in the order of user preference. 2 images are presented to the user for pairwise comparison: one in the first `<img>` tag, the second-in the second `<img>` tag. I want to put the numbers of all the images in an array. Then run the standard JS function sort on this array.

As an argument to the sort function, provide a function that returns 1 if the user likes the left image and -1 if the user likes the second image more. This function will upload an image with the number A to the first `<img>` tag, and an image with the number B to the second `<img>` tag (numbers A and B will be passed to the comparison function from the sort function). For each of the two `<img>` tags, I can define an onClick event handler function that will trigger when the user selects an image uploaded to this `<img>` tag

How should I organize the code to make it work? Do I have to use some tricky combination of setTimeout with callbacks (or promises)?

```
<body>
    <img id = 'img1' src = '1.png' onclick="clickImg(1)">
    <img id = 'img2' src = '2.png' onclick="cliclImg(2)">
</body>

<script>

    let compared = 0;

    function clickImg(img_number){
        if (img_number == 1)
            compared = 1;
        else
            compared = -1; 
    }

    function compare(n1,n2){
        document.getElementById('img1').src = '' + n1 + '.png';
        document.getElementById('img2').src = '' + n2 + '.png';
        
        // Here I should wait for a user click on one of the images

        result = compared;  
        compared = 0;
        return result;
    }

    array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    array.sort(compare);
</script>
```

Comment: That sounds very tricky. You might have to implement your own `.sort` function to make it work asynchronously.

Comment: This is not possible. `sort` requires a synchronous callback. You'll have to implement your own sorting algorithm.